# Rails style lost on link_to nested form

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, nested

I use the nested forms to add a line of form for multiple data entry.
However all the style is lost on the generated forms using link_to.
Looking at the generated code, all the styles are there, but when I add the fields, it doesn't render the style.
I tried the partial that is being rendered as both table row and div row (bootstrap).  The initially generated rows look perfect but the added row are all scrunched up and doesn't align with anything.
Thanks!

In application_helper

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association, readonly)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id=new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
        render("my partial form", f: builder, readonly: readonly)
    end
    link_to(name, "#", class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
```

In my new.html

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>


    <%= f.fields_for :my_association  do |builder| %>
        <%= render "my_partial", f: builder%>
    <% end %>
```

<%= link_to_add_fields "Add New Line", f, :my_association, :readonly=>false%>

In my_partial

```
<tr>
            <td><%= f.collection_select(:customer_id, @customers, :id, :fullname, :include_blank=>'Select') %>
            <%= f.hidden_field(:id)%></td>  
           <td> <%= f.text_field(:description) %></div>         
           <td> <%= f.text_area(:note, :size=> "25x1") %></td>
           <td> <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %><%= link_to "remove", "#", class: "remove_fields"%> </td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a pure HTML/CSS issue.

Its `<thead>` instead of `<theader>` and wrap the partial in `<tbody>`

Try this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <%= f.fields_for :my_association  do |builder| %>
      <%= render "my_partial", f: builder%>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid"><td colspan=6><%= link_to_add_fields "Add New Line", f, :my_association, :readonly=>false%></div></td>
</div>
```

Comment: Those changes didn't make any difference.  And those mistakes were because I quickly changed the layout to table format for this post, and I just got done trying it with <div> layout instead of table layout in case that was the issue.  No change.

Answer (score 0):

I had to wrap my partial in it's own table and take out the row surrounding my call to the partial.  This breaks the table but it's the only way thing will line up.

new.html.erb

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
            ...
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>*</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

<tbody>
    <%= f.fields_for :my_association  do |builder| %>

        <%= render "my_partial", f: builder%>
    <% end %>

<tr>
    <td colspan=6>
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add New Line", f, :my_association, :readonly=>false%>
</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In my paritial

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
    <tr style="width:100%">
            <td><%= f.collection_select(:customer_id, @customers, :id, :fullname, :include_blank=>'Select') %>

            ...

           <td> <%= f.text_area(:note, :size=> "25x1") %></td>
           <td> <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %><%= link_to "remove", "#", class: "remove_fields"%> </td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I would love a better solution but this will work for now.